# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am receiving this error in Python 3.5.1.

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Here is my code:

```
import json
import urllib.request

connection = urllib.request.urlopen('http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_220996.json')

js = connection.read()

print(js)

info = json.loads(str(js))
```

[image]

Comment: This question seems to be receiving a lot of traffic, but the solution is a less common one. If you came here from a search engine, probably also examine the near-duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64378538/requests-throws-json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you look at the output you receive from `print()` and also in your Traceback, you'll see the value you get back is not a string, it's a bytes object (prefixed by `b`):

```
b'{\n  "note":"This file    .....
```

If you fetch the URL using a tool such as `curl -v`, you will see that the content type is

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

So it's JSON, encoded as UTF-8, and Python is considering it a byte stream, not a simple string. In order to parse this, you need to convert it into a string first.

Change the last line of code to this:

```py
info = json.loads(js.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: I am doing the json.loads(js.decode("utf-8")) but it gives an error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @AnwarHussain Then your JSON data (in `js`) is already a string (`str`) and does not need decoding. You can pass it directly to `json.loads()` without the decode function. `json.loads(js)`.

Comment: ```info = json.loads(js.decode("utf-8"))``` worked for me! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

in my case, some characters like "  , :"'{}[]  " maybe corrupt the JSON format, so use *try json.loads(str) except* to check your input

Comment: I am also getting this in vagrant environment :             # 
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/model.py", line 1329, in run
          match.run(runner.context)