# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1) error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, wunderground

```
        f = urlopen('http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY_HERE/geolookup/conditions/q/CA/LosAngeles.json')
        str_response = f.readline().decode('utf-8')
        parsed_json = json.loads(str_response)
        location = parsed_json['location']['city']
        temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
        print ("Current temperature is:", temp_f, " degrees Fahrenheit")
        precep = parsed_json['current_observation']['precep_today_in']
        print("Current wind speed is:", precep)
        wind = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_mph']
        print("Current wind speed is:", wind)
        gust = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_gust_mph']
        print("Current wind gust speed:", gust)
        f.close()
```

I saw this [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579327/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1) and I am unable to figure out how to add this piece of code in.

Here is the error: [image]

Here is my API part as requested:

```
relative_humidity   "81%"
wind_string "Calm"
wind_dir    "NNE"
wind_degrees    23
wind_mph    0
wind_gust_mph   0
wind_kph    0
wind_gust_kph   0
pressure_mb "1012"
pressure_in "29.87"
pressure_trend  "-"
dewpoint_string "53 F (12 C)"
dewpoint_f  53
dewpoint_c  12
heat_index_string   "NA"
heat_index_f    "NA"
heat_index_c    "NA"
windchill_string    "NA"
windchill_f "NA"
windchill_c "NA"
```

Comment: Please show a small portion of the JSON you are trying to parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `f.readline()`, your code only reads the first line that the API returns, which happens to be a blank line, so the JSON encoder complains about no data.

Change `f.readline().decode('utf-8')` to `f.read().decode('utf-8')`, and you should get past this error.